# How to delete one random row at a time in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a project where I need to delete a random row from an Oracle database. Which query should I use for that?

Comment: What have you already tried? You should probably generate a random integer that is a minimum of 1 and a max of the size of the existing database, then delete by primary key

Comment: There is a 1 line query which is enough for that,but I am not getting it

Comment: Again, what have you tried? And why is this question tagged with Java? I don't see anything related to java in the question.

Comment: I'd be curious to know why you need to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well obviously it's a DELETE statement. It's the random part which is tricky.

Oracle has a PL/SQL package to handle randomness, [DBMS_RANDOM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_random.htm#ARPLS040). If the table is small or performance is not critical this will work:

```
delete from your_table
where id = ( select id from 
                (  select id from your_table
                   order by dbms_random.value)
             where rownum = 1)
/
```

The innermost query sorts the table in a random order. The sub-query selects the top row from that set, and that's the row which gets deleted.

Alternatively, if you know how many records you have...

```
delete from your_table
where id = ( select round(dbms_random.value(1,10000))
             from dual )
```

Comment: @Indrapreet Accept the answer and upvote if the answer is correct.